# Errors when trying to run react-native on ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

so I developed an app in react-native, already runs and tested on Android, but now its the ios part.
I'm working with react native version 0.60.3, on MacOS, using yarn as package manager.

I'm running "react-native start --reset cache".
then running "react-native run-ios:" on a separate console,
and getting this error:
"
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening app.xcworkspace.
....
error: Unable to resolve build file: XCBCore.BuildFile (missingTargetProductReference(...))
"

so then im trying to run with Xcode and i get this error on the "react-native start --reset-cache" console: 
"
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from `/Users/nono/work/myapp/.`: The module `./index` could not be found from `/Users/nono/work/myapp/.`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `/Users/nono/work/app/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
"
and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLLQr.png) error on the iphone simulator :

I'm desperate ... please help!
UPDATE:
now the first error doesn’t occur.
I only get the "Unable to resolve './index' ... "
error

Comment: A temporary fix mentioned in react-native github issue* is to use `Legacy Build System`


`File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System -> Legacy Build System`


  *: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24450

Comment: still wont work.. it throws new error in the xcode : ld: library not found for -lRCTGeolocation.
and when im runnign it with react-native run-ios it throws this error:  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/nono/work/myapp/ios/build/myapp/ModuleCache.noindex/3LKJ6B5EN5KJX/CoreFoundation-J9ZOXGK4ZTRR-7b0992c9.pcm.tmp'
Emitted 'error' event at:

Comment: Check if **$ yarn start** works. The metro bundler wasn't able to run on port 8081 for me and I needed to run **$ killall node**

Comment: it seems the metro works fine.. when im running i get the same error again: "
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from `/Users/nono/work/myapp/.`: The module `./index` could not be found from `/Users/nono/work/myapp/.`. Indeed, none of these files exist:* `/Users/nono/work/myapp/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`* `/Users/nono/work/myapp/index/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
"
do i supposed to generate index folder ?

Comment: No, it's only appear on run-ios... maybe a bug. I found some related issue on github react native page.

Comment: `react-native start --reset-cache` do nothing ? @vish

Comment: yes it wont work.... 
damn i get the same "index module cannot be found error" .. :(((

Comment: Found the problem.. Posted it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My bad. I accidentally deleted the index.js ..

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the following commands on terminal:

```
npm install
cd ios; pod install; cd../
react-native link
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Stop the MetroBundler/launchPackager

`Delete node_modules
rm -rf node_modules`

Change the version on your package.json
from

`"react-native": "0.59.1",`
to
`"react-native": "0.58.6",`

Then clean the watchman

`watchman watch-del-all`

Run npm install again:
`npm install`

And try to run your project, in my case:
`react-native run-ios`

Comment: i did what u wrote, down grade from 0.50.3 to 0.58.6, remove the node modules and do  yarn install, and i still get the same error..
also when i tried to run : watchman watch-del-all - i got: "watchman: command not found" error ..